# Can't see rig bones on character

Tags: armature

I am new to blender .
I sculpted a character then pressed shift A, then edit mode but there was not a single rig bone showing.. Went on to even select Infront under viewoint display...
Still nothing.

But the Armature and pose options are showing on the right hand side..

I'm using the newest version of Blender.
Help!

Comment: Use x-ray option.

Comment: New objects are added at the location of the 3D cursor even if the cursor is hidden, so make sure it’s not just off-screen somewhere. You can also try changing object visibility to In Front like already mentioned, or use Local View with `View > Local View` or `Numpad /`.

Comment: Also make sure the armature isn’t hidden, press `alt-H` in object mode to un-hide all or make sure all the eye icons are enabled in the outliner